# Como volcar un array en un select multiple

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario que tiene un select multiple que se carga con los datos de una base de datos. En este select, el usuario selecciona varios "intereses". En el proceso de guardado de los datos, guardo el array en la base de datos con este formato:

```
["17","12","11","13","5"]
```

Ahora viene el momento en que tengo que recuperar lo que el usuario seleccionó. 
Como marco como "selected" aquellos items cuyos values son los que estan guardados en la base de datos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="nombre" multiple>
<?php
$seleccionados = ["17","12","11","13","5"];
foreach($valores as $clave => $nombre) {
    // Verificas si la clave está en los seleccionados
    $sel = (in_array($clave, $seleccionados)) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$clave\"$sel>$nombre</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Estuve probando y no funciona...

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le interesa, esto si funciona:

```
<select id="selectIntereses" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="intereses[]">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <?php
                        //Traigo el array de intereses
                        $valores = json_decode ($intereses, true);

                        $conexion = new Conexion();
                        $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT id, interes FROM intereses WHERE vigente=1 ORDER BY interes");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                          foreach ($valores as $key => $value) {
                              if ($value == $row['id']) { ?>
                                 <option value = "<?php echo $row['id']?>" selected><?php echo utf8_encode($row['interes'])?></option>
                              <?php }else{ ?>
                                 <option value = "<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($row['interes'])?></option>
                              <?php }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
```